# removeEventListner after event has been triggered

Tags: javascript

I have a script that adds a click event to a div to add a new element. Then the function creates and adds the element, and is then supposed to remove the click even from the Div so no farther elements can be added. I understand why the removeEventListener isn't working, but I don't know how to fix it. Here are the lines of code that are giving me the problem:

```
function enable_add(tag, type){return function(e){add_element(e, tag, type);};} //Function call for adding new elements  
document.getElementById("body_visual_editor").addEventListener("click", enable_add(tag, type));  
document.getElementById("body_visual_editor").removeEventListener("click", enable_add());
```

Fire bug says that function(e) is assigned as the event, not enable_add, so the remove event does not find the right event. How do I write these three lines so they all work right?
No javascript libraries please.

Update: So i got the orignal isue sovled by rewriting it like this:

```
var handler;
function enable_add(tag, type) //Function call for adding new elements
{
    handler= function handler(e){add_element(e, tag, type);};
    return handler
}
document.getElementById("body_visual_editor").addEventListener("click", enable_add(tag, type));  
document.getElementById("body_visual_editor").removeEventListener("click", handler);
```

But now it creates a element on the add_element call for etting the handler, and one on click. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Try naming anonymous function , utilizing `Function.prototype.call()` , `Function.prototype.bind()` , `arguments` , to pass `this` , `event` objects

```js
var namedHandler;

function enable_add(tag, type) {
  namedHandler = function namedHandler() {
    add_element.call(this, arguments[arguments.length - 1], tag, type)
  }.bind(this, tag, type);
  return namedHandler
}

function add_element(e, tag, type) {
  var el = document.createElement(tag);
  el.setAttribute("type", type);
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  this.removeEventListener("click", namedHandler)
}

var elem = document.getElementById("body_visusal_editor");
elem.addEventListener("click", enable_add.call(elem, "input", "text"))
```

```html
<div id="body_visusal_editor">click to add one element</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oe71yfn8/

Comment: enable_edd was supposed to return the listener function. This answer solved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Spoke too soon. now I have another issue. When i try to set the handler variable it runs add_element() and creates a empty element, then on the click it creates a second element. How do I stop that? I'll edit my answer to show my changes.

Comment: @Zaper127 Try calling `handler()` before returning refernce to `handler` `handler= function handler(e){add_element(e, tag, type);};
    handler(e);
    return handler`

Comment: uhhh there is no reason to assign to an outer variable here.  just do the assignment when you call the function!

Comment: @guest271314 That would just create a third element

Comment: @Zaper127 Can create jsfiddle , including `add_element` function , to demonstrate ?

Comment: @Eevee The outer variable puts the handler in a global scope, without it the varible is deleted at the end of the function.

Comment: @Zaper127 as in, `var handler = enable_add(...);`.  like any other function that returns a value.  using a global here is ridiculous

Comment: Found the Issue. Eevee helped, though I don't get how her none global solution is supposed to work. But it was because I returned the handler, so the click event was being sent once when the enable_add was being called, then a second time once the handler was returned. By removing the return it fixed the issue. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem:

You've got a partially applied function, that you're passing directly into `addEventListener`.

`removeEventListener` only works on the *exact same function instance as what was passed to `addEventListener`*.

```
function makeFunction () {
  return function () { };
}

var func1 = makeFunction();
var func2 = makeFunction();

func1 === func2; // false
```

So your solution is to cache the created function as a reference, which you then pass into addEventListener, remember it, and pass it into removeEventListener.

```
var myHandler = makeFunction();
el.addEventListener("click", myHandler);
el.removeEventListener("click", myHandler);
```

...of course, you probably don't intend to remove it, instantly.
Which means that you need to get more creative.

```
function handleEventOnce (evt, el, action) {
  function doSomething (e) {
    action(e);
    el.removeEventListener(evt, doSomething);
  }
  el.addEventListener(evt, doSomething);
}

handleEventOnce("click", button, somePartialFunction(a, b));
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling the function again will create a new function, so that won't work.  You would have to store the EventListener as a variable in order to pass it to removeEventListener.